# C - freeing memory allocated in function

Tags: c, function, memory, allocation

I have a function that allocates string and returns its pointer. When I use it directly in call of other function, do I need to free the memory?

For example:

```
char *getRow(){
     char *someString = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
     strcpy(someString , "asdqwezxc");
     return someString;
}

int main(){
     printf("%s", getRow());
}
```

What happens with memory allocated in that function? Is there any way to free it or do I need to store it to some variable before using it?

Comment: This formally leaks the allocated memory. In *this* code it doesn't matter because the program ends immediately thereafter, but it is not good practice.

Comment: That's bad practice, It'd be better to pass the pointer as a reference, so you can allocate and free the string outside the function, just like standard library does.

Comment: If the allocation size is always static like in this example, you could always use a fixed-size buffer that you pass as a parameter to get row.  Like a `char buf[10]; getRow(buf);`  There's limited situations in which that can apply though, and then you have to be very mindful of the calling contract of getRow.  (In other words, probably a bad idea for anything complex unless you have more constraints in place.)

Comment: don't cast the return of `malloc` in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: ok thanks, i'll just use references

Comment: If you have "references" available then *this is not c*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you have returned from the function, the memory is not deallocated unless you explicitly do so. So you must store the return value and call `free`.

```
int main(){
    char* str = getRow();
    printf("%s", str);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, i was just hoping that there is some way, because it's much comfortable calling function like this printf("%s", getRow()); instead of storing it and then using, especially when you need to call that function more times with different parameters

Comment: but how would I return it? local variables die after function ends, dont they?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it in a variable, use it, then free it.  If you don't free it you get a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need. malloc allocate memory from heap which you need to free it explicitly. Variable such as **char *someString** is allocated from stack which will be freed when the function returns. I think you misunderstand stack and heap.

Look at this [what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)